# Can't seem to be able to dissolve edges?

Tags: modeling, uv, sculpting

Hey so I'm relatively new to Blender. I've been following a tutorial to create a catapult but I can't seem to dissolve the edges on a certain part of a wheel. I've done this a number of times before and had no problem with it but now it just doesn't happen.
[image: These two loops don't get deleted]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :D

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe show what part you're talking about and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the URL, I was looking for an upload button but couldn't find one. It's the two loops highlighted in the picture on the inside of the wheel.

Comment: You can see it from the screenshot: multiple edge loops at the same position. Remove extra vertices with: Ctrl V > (Merge) By Distance.

Comment: I tried removing the vertices doing that but I got a dialog box pop up saying removed 0 vertices.

Comment: Did you select everything first?

Comment: I hadn't. Thanks so much for the information, that fixed it!